# Как оптимально решить олимпиадную задачу по арифметике

Tags: олимпиада, арифметика

Пользователь @tokyoghoul00 задал вопрос, который мне удалось решить (может быть не самым оптимальным путем). Может ли кто-то предложить более оптимальный вариант?

Итак, при делении в столбик нужно заменить звездочки цифрами:

[image: Задача на деление]

Ответ: 7375428413 / 125473 = 58781

Алгоритм решения - в моем варианте ответа

Comment: Эх... Похоже, вопрос не связан ни с программированием, ни с ситсемным администрированием. В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) описано, на какие темы тут можно задавать вопросы. В сети Stack Exchange есть специализированный сайт для решений всяких головоломок - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com (на английском).

Comment: Спасибо за линку. А насчет задачки - а вдруг гуру машинного интеллекта подтянутся и расщелкают ее на раз-два...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Третья цифра частного - 7. Строка 6 показывает, что при умножении 6-значного делителя на 7 мы получаем 6-значное число. Значит, первая цифра делителя - **1**
   [image: Шаг 1]
2. Чтобы получить 7 в строке 8, подбираем четвертую цифру частного. Подходящие варианты: 4,7,8,9. С ними коррелируют четвертая и последняя цифры делителя. 4 отпадает, так как с ней не получится 7-значное число при умножении на делитель. 7 и 9 отпадают на шаге 3. Остается **8**. Ей соответствует четвертая цифра делителя **4**
   [image: Шаг 2]
3. Чтобы получить 6-значное число в строке 6, имеются варианты второй цифры делителя: 1,2,3. 1 отпадает, так как не получается 7-значное число в строке 8. 3 отпадает, так как при вычитании результата умножения (строка 6) из 6-значного числа в строке 5 - должны получить 6-значное число в строке 7. Остается **2**. Ему соответствует третья цифра делителя **5**.
   [image: Шаг 3]
4. Определяем дополнительные цифры, умножая первые 3 цифры делителя 125 на известные цифры частного, добавляя сдвиговую 3.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Находим еще несколько цифр в теле вычислений
   [image: Шаг 5]
6. По строке 10 определяем последнюю цифру частного **1** и заполняем известные цифры в строках 9 и 10.
   [image: Шаг 6]
7. То ли мозг уже кипит, то ли этот шаг самый сложный. Выбираем последнюю цифру делителя из вариантов 1,2,3,4. Приходится использовать перебор, выполняя вычисления, чтобы получить 7 в строке 3 на шаге 8. Подошел вариант **3**. Вычисляем цифры в строках 5-10.
   [image: Шаг 7]
8. Здесь все просто - вычисляем вторую цифру частного. Если был правильный выбор на шаге 7 - все получится. Цифра **8**. Заполняем строки 3,4 и часть строки 1.
   [image: Шаг 8]
9. Завершающее усилие - находим первую цифру частного - **5**. Задача решена!
   [image: Шаг 9]